# How to pass user defined objects with a CXF REST client?

Tags: android, cxf

I'm developing an android application that needs to connect to a remote database through a CXF web service.I have tried using Soap but due to various problems left the option and went for a light weight REST based service(by adding the annotations to the existing cxf web service).I have a Rest client which is called from inside the activity.
I worked with simple parameters like String,int etc.Now i Want to pass a user Defined object 
to the service and get some String value from the server side.How do i do this?
Please help...On googling i found articles about using JSON,JAXB etc but I don know what these do or how i use these either. I am very new to programming using these technologies.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something similar for your client code:

```
private static final String URI = "http://localhost/rest/customer";

private Customer readCustomer(String id) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URI + "/" + id);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

        InputStream data = connection.getInputStream();
        // TODO - Read data from InputStream

        connection.disconnect();
        return customer;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void createCustomer(Customer customer) {
    try { 
        URL url = new URL(URI);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        // TODO - Write data to OutputStream
        os.flush();

        connection.getResponseCode();
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URI);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        // TODO - Write data to OutputStream
        os.flush();

        connection.getResponseCode();
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void deleteCustomer(String id) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URI + "/" + id);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
        connection.getResponseCode();
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```